# When to use Collection<T> or IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, collections

I've seen similar questions but I'm still lost in regards to the return type of Public, Internal and Private methods. When should my return type by Collection and when should it be IEnumerable

The [MSDN guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)  says

> X DO NOT use weakly typed collections in public APIs.
>
> The type of all return values and parameters representing collection items should be the exact item type, not any of its base types (this applies only to public members of the collection).

This has totally confused me and implies that everything (public) should be `Collection<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. My confusion comes in when can we use `List<T>`,  for example

```
public Collection<string> DoThisThing(int i)
{
     Collection<string> col = new Collection<string>();
     List<string> myList = null;
     if (i > 0)
         myList = GetListOfString();

     //col.AddRange(...); Can't AddRange as no method
     //return myList; Can't do this as it expects return type of Collection<string>

     //So, to ensure my return is Collection, I have to convert
     foreach(var item in myList)
     {
         col.Add(item);
     }

     return col;
}
```

In the above example, it's perfectly valid that List is a better choice, so, if I want to use `AddRange`, I could either

1. Hope to have control of API so I can change the return type of GetListOfString to Collection (not always possible)
2. Add an extension method to Control to support AddRange
3. Type it out every time, as I do above

However, if I do option 1, then I don't see when I'd ever actually use `ToList()` (other than when I have to if an external API returns List) as all my return types would be either `Collection<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Using option 2 seems more sensible but, now I'm lost as it feels as if I'm forcing it to do something it isn't intended to do.

Option 3 is repetitive

Whist I appreciate it will always depend on the situation, as a general rule, is the following accurate

**Public** - Should be very precise, for example `IEnumerable<string>` (note, not `T`), but not `Collection<T>`/`Collection<string>`

**Internal and private** - Should be more agnostic, so `Collection<T>` is better (and live with not really using List or if I do have to use, I will have to cast it into `Collection<T>`

Comment: Use a collection if you want to allow that the caller can `Add` things, use an `IEnumerable<T>`  if you don't want that. Consider a method `GetAdminUsers()`. What would you return? But it's not about safety but readability. You can always cast it to the real type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, you've kindly helped me many, many times in the past, so sorry to target you directly with this, but do you feel the extension method is a hack or would be OK (as per my 2nd bullet point)?

Comment: Also, `IEnumerable<T>` implies that you will only enumerate it *once*. And be aware that `IEnumerable<T>` can potentially be infinite, while `ICollection<T>` has a `Count`. And you can access an item in an `ICollection<T>` by index.

Comment: There is a difference between `Collection<T>` and `ICollection<T>`! Which is it you are really referring to?

Comment: @Dave: i'm not sure if i've understood the core of your question. What are you trying to achieve, what are your concerns? You can always return a `List<string>` as `IEnumerable<string>`. Maybe you are also confusing public APIs with public methods. The former means that it's acessible from outside of your project (f.e. a webservice).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, again, you're right... That is a bit part of it. Yes, I've just started to update all my public methods to use Collection<T> instead of IList<T> or IEnumerable<T>. Thank you so much, yet another beer on me for this

Comment: @flindeberg, I'm lost, I never mention ICollection<T>

Comment: Do you *have* to use `Collection<T>` instead of `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` (or `ICollection<T>`, sorry, I think i introduced that into the discussion)? What benefits do you think you have using `Collection<T>`?

Comment: @Corak: "IEnumerable<T> implies that you will only enumerate it once" - I don't think that should be assumed by default, and when it is assumed, it needs to be stated in the docs for the respective enumerable.

Comment: @Corak, no benefit at all. This is the issue, I read up on the [MSDN guidline for collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure I was doing things right and got confused between API and public methods, and spent the morning trying to convert every List into a Collection<T> or ReadOnlyCollection<T> :(  ARGH. Sorry for a confused quesiton!

Comment: "Weakly typed" might refer to something like `ArrayList`, which can contain any type of object and *should never ever be used ever*! `List<T>` is absolutely strongly typed. First, you can be sure that it will only ever contain items of type `T` (or derivates) and second, a `List<T>` is completely different from `List<K>`, assuming `T` and `K` are different.

Comment: @Dave, exactly, but comparing `Collection<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>` is like comparing a Leopard Mark 2 with the concept of a vehicle with an internal combustion engine. Comparing `ICollection<T>` on the other hand makes more sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** added code at the end

---

You are confusing several different layers of the guide.

In your internal code you are free to do what you like, albeit there are guidelines for how to write code that is clean, readable and easy to maitain. Still, those are implementation details and they are tucked away behind your public methods, so you can do what you want (you may shoot in your own foot).

Artifacts you write to be used by other developers are one of these:

- libraries;
- frameworks;
- modules of "some kind".

Now, in these cases you must decide:

- the boundaries of your artifact;
- how those developers use your artifact.

The boundaries are well defined by an assembly, if you choose to have one.

> Sometimes namespaces may be considered "internal boundaries" and the consumer is yourself, in the future. Organizing your code into internal boundaries is a good practice but consider that classes already define boundaries so don't overdo it. Group 10-20 classes in a namespace by **cohesion** and keep those groups apart without interdependencies by **low coupling**. You cannot really understand what I mean here when I say *bridge*... but come back in a year or so and read this answer again :)

How to use the assembly is defined in these places:

- manifest (generated automatically by the VS packaging);
- documentation (which should accompany your assembly);
- source code (if you expose it);
- public constructs (enums, interfaces, classes, namespaces, package dependencies);
- public and protected methods.

Now with all those tools you have a way to design that thing called an **API**.
There is plenty of room to maneuver and make mistakes. Because of this, the good people at M$ decided to define a uniform and consistent way of designing the default APIs in the default assemblies and namespaces (such as `System.*`).

What you have touched in your question is a guideline to API designers (which you might or might not be). All they say is:

> if you are designing an API such as a non-internal method of a public class in an accessible assembly, than do us the favor and return a tightly defined value, as concrete as possible.

So, if it is a `List<T>` don't return any of the ancestors such as `IEnumerable<T>` or whatever. This allows the consumers (other developers) of your assembly to leverage concrete properties of your return value.

On the other hand you should accept as general values as possible. If you just use a method of `IEnumerable<T>` in your method you should require just that:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> e);
```

This *signature* of your method allows consumers to pass in many different concrete collections. The only thing you require is that it is (derives from) an `IEnumerable<T>`.

These design decisions are also bound to many important OO principles of SOLID. They postulate that:

- you should depend on abstractions => so expose interfaces if possible and keep your API abstract;
- you should hide implementation details so that changes in your assembly don't propagate to consumer code;
- you should avoid changing the API by allowing extension mechanism.

To be more precise I take your code and try to be as concrete as possible:

```
public List<string> DoThisThing(int i) // use list to return a more concrete type
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>(); // you really want a *LIST* so why be abstract in your own code innards?
    // List<string> myList = null; <-- superfluous
    if (i > 0)
    {
        list = GetListOfString();
    } // ALWAYS (!) use code blocks, see the book "Clean Code"

    // this problem is solved: in your internal code don't be abstract if you don't need it
    //col.AddRange(...); Can't AddRange as no method

    return list; // Can't do this as it expects return type of Collection<string>

    // you're done...

    // So, to ensure my return is Collection, I have to convert
    // foreach(var item in myList)
    // {
    //     col.Add(item);
    // }

    // return col;
}
```

Some help about the theory behind all this: [The SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

What you really want to understand is how and why you need abstractions. When you really grasp that, you will also understand when you DO NOT need them and so decide in a reasoned manner when to use `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<string>` without negative repercussions on the rest of your code. The most important principles of SOLID are in this case OCP and DIP.

Comment: What a stunning answer!

Comment: "In your internal code you are free to do what you like" - rather than this stance, I prefer a "golden rule" like "If in any way possible, always design internal APIs the same you would design public APIs." Or, in other words: "Keep the inside of your house at least as clean as the outside."

Comment: Great answer! Just one thing. I'd say only return a `List<T>` if you *want it to be used* as a `List<T>`. And even then, you might be better of returning an `IList<T>`. If you later change your internal implementation to use something other than `List<T>`, you will introduce a breaking change. If you return an `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` or even an `IEnumerable<T>` you're completely free to use whatever you want internally, as long as it implements the returned interface.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yeah that's how I separate concerns in a system. Even when I know I'm the only one using some artifacts I still try to subdivide and have "internal boundaries" which often coincide with nested namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to be thinking into the "wrong" direction, starting from the initial MSDN quotation:

> X DO NOT use weakly typed collections in public APIs.
>
> The type of all return values and parameters representing collection items should be the exact item type, not any of its base types (this applies only to public members of the collection).

This refers to the *items* of collections, not the collection types.

This guideline does not refer to the type of the collection itself at all. Whether you return an enumerable, a collection, a list, or any other collection type, entirely depends on how you intend your collection to behave and what guarantees you want to make about the *set* of items you store.

The guideline you cited, on the other hand, indicates that you should strongly type the *items* stored in your collection. That is, if you have a list of `string` values, do not declare the collection item type as `object` (e.g. by typing the collection to `IEnumerable<object>` or `IList<object>`), but do use `string` as the item type (e.g. `IEnumerable<string>`, `ICollection<string>`, `IList<string>`).

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling because the second bullet on the guide says don't use List<T> so I thought it meant T = weakly typed and <something> is strongly typed!

Comment: @Dave: That refers to yet another issue: What MSDN means in that bullet point is, do not use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (a particular collection class), instead use [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (an interface that is implemented by `List<T>`, but which can also be implemented by any other custom class) if you need the members of a list.

Comment: Even `T[]` implements `IList<T>`, so you could even change your implementation to return an array without breaking the code.

Comment: I totally agree. Furthermore, if possible and under **certain circumstances** it is better to remove the actual type completely: `public List<T> DoThisThing<T>(int i)`. This way he ends up with only "structure", which would be the gist of the method. Often this is overshoot, but to keep an eye on those opportunities is a good thing.